# char *str vs char str[] : segmentation issue

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void test(char *p)
{
     p = p + 1;
     *p = 'a';
}

int main()
{
    char *str = "Hello";
    test(str);
    printf("%s", str);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it gives segmentation error ? why is this happening. The const theory is not clear to me... whereas if I declare str as char str[], it does the job. Are they not both basically the same things ?

Comment: Pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score 7):

`str` is pointing to a string literal, you are attempting to modify the string literal in the function `test` on this line:

```
*p = 'a';
```

It is [`undefined behavior`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to attempt to modify a string literal. You can alternatively, make a copy of the string literal into a array as follows:

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

now it is perfectly ok to modify `str`. From the [`draft C99 standard`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), under section `6.4.5 String literals` paragraph `6`:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

Answer (score 5):

```
*p = 'a';
```

The problem is the above statement tries to modify the read only segment. String literal `"Hello"` resides in read only segment and can not be modified.

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

The above statement copies `Hello` to `str` character array and the array contents can be modified.